# Const variable accessible in whole file

Tags: ecmascript-6, reactjs

I'm wondering why this piece of code works:

```
 class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
         <Widget />

        </div>
      );
    }
  }

 const Widget = () => {return <h1>hello</h1>};
```

I thought **const variable** should be invisible for App class (TDZ).

Comment: Why did you think that?

Comment: Normally (eg in browser) if I try to access const variable, in the same block it was declared, but before it was declared I will end up having `ReferenceError`. Why babel allows it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const` variable accessible in block scope, `App` and `Widget` are in the same scope in your example

UPDATE:
This situation is not related to babel or react or webpack.
You are just mixing up two javascript concepts `calling` and `defining`. Your example might look like this and it will be the same situation.

```
// function definition
function app() {
  console.log(a);
}

// variable definition
const a = 2;

// function call
app();
```

This code logs `2` to console. Javascript trying to access variable `a` only when `app` function calls.

Next example

```
// function definition
function app() {
  console.log(a);
}

// function call
app();

// variable definition and variable assignment
const a = 2;
```

,will log `undefined` to console because function was called before const `a` assigned

Comment: In browser this: `(function () { console.log(a); const a = 2; })()` returns `ReferenceError`. Constants are block-scoped, but all the considerations about the "temporal dead zone" that apply to let, also apply to const.

Comment: This is another situation, `console.log(a)` calls before `2` has been assigned to `a`

Comment: How is this different from the code I provided? I'm also using `Widget` before it was declared...

Comment: You are not  calling method `render()` before `Widget` assigned. You just defines it

Comment: Thanks! Now it make sense.

Answer (score 1):

`Widget` is in scope throughout the file (constants are block-scoped but you have declared `Widget` in the outermost scope).

You're not accessing `Widget` until `render()` is called, by which time, it will have been assigned a value.

Comment: Thanks it's clear now.  Still I don't get why when I have sth like `(function () { console.log(a); const a = 2; })()` why babel transpile it to `var` without any warnings?

Comment: @Adrian to be honest I'm not sure why Babel doesn't give you a warning there but that situation is different to the one in your question, because you're accessing the variable before it has been declared.

Comment: Sure, now I understand it's different issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are right but wrong. The code that actually runs doesn't have `const` or `class` in it. Below is the code that gets executed.

If in doubt, paste your code into the [babel repl](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-2&code=class%20App%20extends%20React.Component%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20render()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CWidget%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20const%20Widget%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7Breturn%20%3Ch1%3Ehello%3C%2Fh1%3E%7D%3B%0D%0A%20) and you'll see what will get executed by the browser.

```
"use strict";

var _createClass = function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; }();

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

function _possibleConstructorReturn(self, call) { if (!self) { throw new ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called"); } return call && (typeof call === "object" || typeof call === "function") ? call : self; }

function _inherits(subClass, superClass) { if (typeof superClass !== "function" && superClass !== null) { throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not " + typeof superClass); } subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, { constructor: { value: subClass, enumerable: false, writable: true, configurable: true } }); if (superClass) Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass; }

var App = function (_React$Component) {
  _inherits(App, _React$Component);

  function App() {
    _classCallCheck(this, App);

    return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, Object.getPrototypeOf(App).apply(this, arguments));
  }

  _createClass(App, [{
    key: "render",
    value: function render() {
      return React.createElement(
        "div",
        null,
        React.createElement(Widget, null)
      );
    }
  }]);

  return App;
}(React.Component);

var Widget = function Widget() {
  return React.createElement(
    "h1",
    null,
    "hello"
  );
};
```